# How to write a PY encoder for AQA GCSE NEA

Tags: python

So, I'm doing my GCSE AQA NEA... it is all about RLE compression. We have to use ASCII art not image compression. The encoder found online, works but I need to add a 0 to and singular numbers to make a double digit. 
for example, `1` becomes `01`. `5` becomes `05`.

I have tried to rewrite the encoder, but I have a 20-hour time limit and don't want to waste time. The code I found uses "lambda":

```py
def encode(input_string):
    encoded_line = sub(r'(.)\1+', lambda x: str(len(x.group(0))) + x.group(1), input_string)    #https://exercism.io/tracks/python/exercises/run-length-encoding/solutions/5b462f4375794cd5b50c7faa4a17e459
    return encoded_line
```

The output of `,ad888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888da,` is `,ad578da,`, but I need it to be `01,01a01d57801d01a01,`
How can I get this desired output?

Comment: what you describe and your example do not match: you say that you should do is convert e.g. `5` to `05`, but in your example you just put `01` almost everywhere except the RLE core `578`.

Comment: @norok2 so, because ```8``` is a character in the ASCII art, this means it doesn't need to be ```5708```. Because 57 is in the double digits it doesn't need a ```0```. I'm sorry this wasn't explained in the best way.

Comment: Still, this does not explain why / what is the rule for adding `01` before `,`, `a` and `d`.